# How to create a DependancyProperty Collection with bindable Items in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I need to create a DependancyProperty Collection
and somehow bind or be able to know when each item changes

It is not easy to explain this problem..

To declare a simple DependancyProperty we do that:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColor", typeof(Color),
    typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));

public Color SelectedColor
{
 get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedColorProperty); }
 set { SetValue(SelectedColorProperty, value); }
}
```

And later on in XAML we can do that:

```
<MyClass SelectedColor="{Binding blah blah}"/>
```

If I add a simple callback on value change in the static declaration so instead of
just `new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Red)`
i'll have: `new PropertyMetaData(Colors.Red,MyCallback)` 
Each time the value is changed I will be able to react to that change from code behind.

Ok, now what I want is something that will be written in XAML like that:

```
<MyClass>
   <MyClass.SelectedColors>
    <Color>{Binding blah1}</Color>
    <Color>{Binding blah2}</Color>
    <Color>{Binding blahN}</Color>
   <MyClass.SelectedColors>
</MyClass>
```

However, I can't use multibinding as I want to know which color has
changed and multibinding gives me an aggregator tactic, meaning when
I done writing the multibinding converter I will get all the values
from all "blahs" at the same time and will not be able to know which
one was the one that changed..

I began writing something simple that look as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedColorsProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedColors", typeof(List<Color>),
       typeof(MyClass),
           new PropertyMetadata(new List<Color>()));

  public List<Color> SelectedColors
        {
            get { return (List<Color>)GetValue(SelectedColorsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SelectedColorsProperty, value); }
        }

   public MyClass()
        {
            foreach(var item in SelectedColors)
            {
        //dunno what goes here.. or how to bind the color change?
            }
        }
```

So now I can't create a callback that will handle each change of each item, right?
Yet that is exactly what I need, to be able to react to a change in each item..

However it does allow me to express the XAML syntax I need..

Any ideas? Did anyone bumped into that kind of problem before?
I noticed very short explanation in MSDN but i'm not sure if it helps me and how
to use it if can help, it is the last paragraph in the page that mentions
something about using a

```
Freezable<T>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563.aspx

I appreciate your help, 
Thanks.

---

Update: A MultiBinding Solution can also be ok if it will allow to distinguish which of the values had the change (in our example which color changed). 
The Markup in that case might look like that:

```
<MyClass>
   <MyClass.SelectedColors>
      <MultiBinding..
        <Binding Path="FillColor" ElementName="MyRectWhichHasFillColorDProperty"/>
        <Binding blah2 which is Color2 />
        <Binding blah3 which is ColorN />
```

Comment: did you try using ObserableCollection?

Comment: hmm why? I don't need to know when items are being added or removed or replaced or cleared from the Collection - all i need to know is when the items themselfs are changed, in example Color red changed to Color green.

Comment: I think there will be no escape than somehow do it Multibinding.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Colors in a class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and then setup a listener to the PropertyChanged event for each color in your constructor.

Wrapper class

```
public class ColorViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Color color;
    public Color Color
    {
        get { return color; }
        set
        {
            if (value != color)
            {
                color = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Color");
            }
        }
    }

    // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation goes here
}
```

Then in your event listener you will get the individual ColorViewModel that fired the property changed event.

I have had to solve a very similar problem before and I created an ObservableCollection of my ViewModel class so that I could subscribe to an collection changes and attach/detach my event listeners to the changed items.

I typed this from memory on my Surface so there are probably lots of typos and you should take the code sample as sudo code.

Hope this helps.

EDIT

Here is what your Xaml could look like:

```
<namespace:MyClass>
    <namespace:MyClass.SelectedColors>
        <namespace:ColorViewModel Color="{Binding SomeValue}" />
        <namespace:ColorViewModel Color="{Binding OtherValue}" />
    </namespace:myClass.SelectedColors>
</namespace:MyClass>
```

where `Colors` is a collection of `ColorViewModel`.

You will not be able to wire up your `PropertyChanged` listeners in your constructor since at the time of construction there are no ColorViewModels in Colors, so I would just make Colors an `ObservableCollection` and use the `CollectionChanged` event to wire up `PropertyChanged` listeners to any new additions to the collection.

You may just want to Use a SolidColorBrush instead of a ColorViewModel class as it has a `Color` property and a `Changed` event.

Comment: first of all - thank you. but how things would look in the XAML side? keep mind I specifically listed how the XAML need to look like when working with it.

Comment: I added an example of what your `Xaml` could look like.  I think with a bit of time it could match even closer.  I have tested this since I was shooting from the hip on my original post, and it works for me.